# Does Replace function in postgres have except cases

Tags: postgresql

How can i use the replace function with some except conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Try using a regular expression if you need more control over what is being replaced.

```
regexp_replace(string text, pattern text, replacement text [,flags text])
```

If regex isn't enough then create your own function in [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql.html)

Answer (score 1):

> How can i use the replace function with some except conditions.

Such as? Of course, SpliFF is absolutely right, you can use regexp_replace, as that would give you more control over what is matched, but in case you're talking about another condition, can't you just use a where clause?

```
UPDATE foo SET bar = REPLACE( bar, 'foo', 'bar' ) WHERE yourcondition IS TRUE;
```